# Chrome extension: Change URL of links when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension which changes the URLs pointed to by certain links posted on Facebook. At first I thought of doing a simple regex search and substitution in `$(document).ready()`, but Facebook loads a lot of home screen content dynamically, so a lot of stuff will be left out. I then wrote this method:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    console.log(this.href);
}
```

...and I can then do matching etc on `this.href` the question is, how do I change the destination of the link when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', yourdestination);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for Facebook links that open in the same tab, but would I be able to give it the same behaviour for links that open in a new tab? Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Yes, just make sure to add (or change) the target attribute to _blank : $(this).attr('target', "_blank");

Comment: I've done that, but there's some strange behaviour: external links from Facebook seem to get picked up by this method, but when I change the href and target values the print out the object, the href isn't changed on these links. Is this just something weird Facebook does with its external links? I've also set the 'onmousedown' attribute to null which removes it from all links, but that hasn't made it work either.